# How to change actionbar menu button with click on tab

Tags: android, android-studio, android-viewpager, android-actionbar

There is 2 tab in activity first is image and second is video i want when there is image tab the menu button will be image on actionbar and when click on video tab the button change into video button. i am new on android and no idea what to do.

Comment: Can you add screenshot of your layout?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the onMenuCreated method and by managing the flag of which tab you're in, create a menu item accordingly. The menu item should be set to show as action button (so it will be visible in the action bar).

Another approach is to create a toolbar layout, add the two buttons and manage their visibility.